# Java Add Text in Tab Delimited From String Array To String Vector

Tags: java, arrays, vector, tabs, delimited

I am having trouble formatting tab delimited text to Vector. Would you please provide help to achieve this?

My String Array **data** holds these texts.

```
LastName    FirstName   Address City    State   Phone   
Berry   Rachel  240 Woodbridge Rd.  West Haven  CT  (203) 933- 5678
Dillon  John    29 Howe Ave.    Derby   CT  (203) 735- 4532
...................
...................
...................
```

I tried to have another sub for-loop to split the text by tabs then add to row String Vector but I ran into Out of System Memory error. I also tried the use the addAll property from the Vector but it added row 1 (Berry...) to first field, row 2 to second field and so on.

Here is my code and it does not work as expected.

```
rowData = new Vector<Vector>();
row = new Vector<String>();

ReadFile filedata = new ReadFile(); 
data = filedata.OpenFile(); 

for(int i = 0; i <data.length; i++)
   {
       row.add(data[i].split("\\t").toString());                                                                       
   }

rowData.addElement(row);
```

How do I format the data so it will split by tab into different fields? For reference, here is the manual way of how I need it.

```
Vector<String> rowOne = new Vector<String>();
rowOne.addElement("Berry");
rowOne.addElement("Rachel");
rowOne.addElement("240 Woodbridge Rd.");
rowOne.addElement("West Haven");
rowOne.addElement("CT");
rowOne.addElement("(203) 933- 5678");

Vector<String> rowTwo = new Vector<String>();
rowTwo.addElement("Dillon");
rowTwo.addElement("John");
rowTwo.addElement("29 Howe Ave.");
rowTwo.addElement("Derby");
rowTwo.addElement("CT");
rowTwo.addElement("(203) 735- 4532");
```

I hope I've made myself clear enough and any inputs will be much appreciated. Thank you all.

---

EDIT: I was able to get rid of the OutOfMemoryError with double for-loop but below code fill my Vector with first line 10 times which is the number of rows in array.

EDIT2: This loops return with 10 rows, and 54 fields in each row. That means all the texts from data array were splitted and and insert into these 10 rows, so all these 10 rows have the same set of data. That why my table was filled with the first line 10 times.

```
rowData = new Vector<Vector>();
        row = new Vector<String>();

        ReadFile filedata = new ReadFile(); 
        data = filedata.OpenFile();             

        for(int i = 1; i <data.length; i++)
        {
            lines = data[i].split("\t"); 
            for(int x = 0; x < lines.length; x++)
            {
                row.addAll(Arrays.asList(lines[x]));                    
            }                
            rowData.addElement(row);                                                                      
        }
```

Comment: I guess that your first try with a second loop is a good way, did you try to get rid of the OutOfMemoryError ? can you post this code ?

Comment: After a good sleep, I was able get rid of the OutOfMemoryError, but  it filled the Vector with first row 10 times. Please see edit section in my questions. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Whats the type of data variable, also can you post the content of data[i] (any index).

Comment: @nash_ag: the content of data[i] is the same as the one I posted above and it's String[] array.

Comment: I think my for-loops is the problem. Because I can see that there are 10 rows in my rowData Vector, and 54 fields in each row. That means the whole texts in data array have been splitted by tabs and insert into rowData.

Comment: can you display the result of System.println(data[0]) ?

Comment: @syllabus: data[0] shows the first line of the text above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the structure of read file method and problem solved. Thank you for all your input guys.